# How to use ffmpeg speedup video specific time range in one line ffmpeg cli

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, video

I try following splited cli, they work well

```
ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=10,setpts=PTS/10[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=0:end=10,asetpts=PTS/10[a1]" -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" -shortest -t 1 "$output_file" -y
ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=10:end=13,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=10:end=13,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]" -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" -shortest "$output_file" -y
```

but when i merge them:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=10,setpts=PTS/10[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=0:end=10,asetpts=PTS/10[a1];[0:v]trim=start=10:end=13,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=10:end=13,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]" -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" -shortest -t 4 "$output_file" -y
```

the result video last 3s is frozen, how to fix it

If I found following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878406/6011193), but it give multi lines ffmpeg solution, I hope one ffmpeg cli todo it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use concat filter to merge them.

`ffmpeg -i "$input_file" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=0:end=10,setpts=PTS/10[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=0:end=10,asetpts=PTS/10[a1];[0:v]trim=start=10:end=13,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=start=10:end=13,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" "$output_file" -y`